# Mono with C# - Converting a WinForms interface over to Cocoa? (or whatever the default OS X interface is)

Tags: winforms, cocoa, macos, mono, porting

I have a C# app that I've managed to get working with Mono and running on OS X. The application itself runs just fine, but it doesn't really look all that good when run on OS X. The button fonts look jagged, and many of the default features that are there for the Windows 7 version aren't present. To me it sort of looks like a Win98 application with an OS X top border taped to it.

I'm looking into possibly learning Objective-C so that I can write 'proper' OS X apps, but for the moment I'd like to be able to get my projects working on an Apple without having them look Frankensteined together.

**Is it possible to convert a WinForms app over to Cocoa? Is Cocoa the correct interface to use?**

**If possible, what's the best way to go about it, and do any of you know of a good tutorial/writeup on the process to get me started?** It'd be nice to see something that actually shows the process being done. I learn far more from example code along with a short explanation than I do from a generic article.

Thanks again!

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=94481&id=1500469566&l=85716508e7

Comment: I hope the facebook link works. It shows an example of a WinForms application being ported to Cocoa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create a native looking OSX application, you are correct that you want to use Cocoa.  If you still want to use C#, you can use [MonoMac](http://mono-project.com/MonoMac).

MonoMac allows you to build your GUI natively on OSX (in fact, using the Interface Builder shipped by Apple), but allows you to write your app in .Net/C#.  This way you can continue to use your existing application logic and only have to change the GUI code.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty much universally true that a ported app will always look like a ported app. Even large companies with huge budgets can't pull off anything better (I cite Adobe - what a mess).

Slapping a Mac face on a Windows app port will show its seams. If you want the application to behave like a native application (and take advantage of the performance-related goodies the platform offers), the absolute best approach is to use the architectural documentation, specs, and requirements I know you have - conscientious developer that you are - to adapt the design to the native platform. That's the Cocoa Frameworks (the API), which are written in Objective-C (the language).

There's quite simply no other path that doesn't end with a crappy-looking port that's riddled with bugs and behavioral problems born of the porter's insufficient familiarity with the target platform. This *isn't* just limited to Mono/C#-to-Cocoa/Obj-C. The opposite is just as true. Even Java-for-PlatformA-to-Java-for-PlatformB ports of desktop apps suffer these problems. Start with a solid architecture and build for the platform if you want the best user experience.

That said, you're already a step ahead by realizing this and wanting to do better. Bravo! :-) Though I don't know of any tutorials for this path, I'd suggest even that's not the correct approach since you indicated you're looking for quality. Avail yourself of the many Cocoa books and many more online communities (like this one) and learn the platform before committing to your Cocoa-adapted architecture and code base.

**Update based on comment debate**

To be clear: I'm not saying there's no way or that there's no tool out there that makes it possible. There're actually plenty I've seen but don't recall and won't bother googling. My point remains: the OP is concerned with quality of native appearance (and I assume behavior and possibly performance) and porting tools / translation layers don't achieve this due to inherent differences in the platform's architecture and user experience idioms. The OP suspects it might be best to learn the platform and build specifically for it and I'm agreeing. Your opinion may vary. Have at it.

Comment: Look at the question: "Is it possible to convert a WinForms app over to Cocoa? Is Cocoa the correct interface to use?" Assuming the actual model and business logic are decoupled from the WinForms application, it is entirely possible to reuse it under a Obj-C & Cocoa reimplementation of the views exclusively. Win/win: Important C# bits are retained and nobody will know it isn't a completely native application. Here: http://fallingcanbedeadly.com/posts/about-nsducttape P.S. Many Mac only "fully native" Cocoa applications use C/C++ under Obj-C for model and business logic, too.

Comment: @Joel: It looks like you missed the point of both the question and my answer (or I'm WAY off base). I never said it wasn't possible - I said, given the OPs desire not to have it look (and I assume behave) like a bad port, the best option is to build for the platform and not to port at all. Additionally, since Objective-C is a superset of C, it's all C anyway - it's just that using Cocoa's native language is the path of least resistance.

Comment: @Joel: Regarding your link, this goes back to "sure, it's possible" but the devil is in the details. As the OP intimated, there are plenty of pitfalls using any sort of translation/adaptation layer. It's not reasonable to expect a direct architecture-to-architecture mapping of functionality and behavior, hence the "this looks like a crappy port" sensation you get when you use such an application.

Comment: @Joel as for your PS: even the WebKit itself is an Objective-C veneer on top of a C++ framework ;)

Comment: @Yuji: Let's maintain the distinction between "desktop application" and "library/framework". :-)

Comment: I disagree with your assertions that rewriting the entire app is required to do a good native interface. You can have a great native Mac interface whether the code behind is C#, C++, C, Obj-C, Java or anything else, and you can just as easily have a horrible un-Maclike interface even if the code is all 'pure' Objective-C.

Comment: Assuming that the UX is altered to follow the platform guidelines, native AppKit controls are used for the UI, all dependencies are included in the application package and standard directories like ~/Library/Preferences are used, etc., I seriously doubt that anyone would notice that the underlying business logic was written in a language other than Obj-C. If user experience is seamless, customers are happy and OP is saved from an immense amount of duplicated effort, everybody wins.